# String to Python statement?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert a string to a Python statement.

1. Taking string input from a text file e.g. `'dataframe['Column_name'].sum()'`
2. Executing the string as a Python statement e.g. `dataframe['Column_name'].sum()`
3. Storing the result in some variable

Comment: What are you actually trying to *achieve*? Where do those strings come from? Do you really need to store the whole statement?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this, but not recommended. You do not have any control over what the string contains if it comes from the user. There is probably a better way to achieve what you *really* want.

If you really, absolutely, unavoidably have to, you can use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```
x = eval('dataframe["Column_name"].sum()')
```

But it is probably easier to only take, for example, the column name from the user and use that in a function call:

```
column_name = "Column_name"  # or read it from the file
x = dataframe[column_name].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#previous code
with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    x = eval(f.readline())
    #the rest of the code, using x however you want
```

I wouldn't do it if other users are supposed to be able to use the script however they want. If this is for learning purposes of for your own use, it's up to you.